# Is $\frac{(p-1)^p+1}{p^2}$ square-free?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Is $\frac{(p-1)^p+1}{p^2}$ squarefree for all primes $p \geq 7$? I did some small testing and it seems to hold up to $p \leq 47$. Also, note that the above expression is indeed an integer by binomial expansion.

Comment: Very interesting. The probability that a random integer is square-free is about $.6$, so these fifteen data points might seem very convincing, but there is a bias that increases that probability significantly for these numbers, because are not divisible by any prime p or below. (An earlier version of this comment overstated the probability.) So my guess is we should keep looking for a counterexample. The computation gets very slow though!

Comment: If $q^2$ divides $(p-1)^p+1$ then $q\equiv\pm1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: This question should not be getting close votes. It's an interesting question, it's not homework (in any reasonable class), OP has shown work, it's not at all clear what the answer is.

Comment: @Servaes Would you mind explaining why that's true?

Comment: @Servaes Just thinking... if $q \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$, then $q$ is even (since $p$ is odd by hypothesis). Consequently $q^2$ is even and there is only one even prime...

Comment: @MarcoRipà That's not true - $q$ can be $2p+1$, for example, which is odd.

Comment: @Servaes I think even $q\equiv 1\pmod p$ is necessarily true, since the order of $p-1$ mod $q$ must be exactly $2p$ (unless $q=p$ which I haven't bothered to rule out, presumably by working out the $p$-adic expansion of $(p-1)^p$).

Comment: If, heuristically, we look at the "expectation" of the number of primes squared dividing such $p$'s, every $q$ only has $O(\frac{\log(q)}{\log(\log(q))})$ possible $p$'s it might divide, so the total number is $\sum_{q}{O(\frac{\log(q)}{\log(\log(q)) q^2})}$, which converges, so we should only expect a limited number of counterexamples, if there are any. I can confirm with a computer there aren't for for $q\leq10^7$, so the remaining "probability" is $\approx 9 \cdot 10^{-6}$.

Comment: This situation reminds me of this preprint of mine about an old open problem in recreational mathematics (https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.10163)... very very low chances to get a counterexample, but very hard to prove that there can't be any.
I will look forward if this problem will be solved since I think that it won't be an easy task.

Comment: @ErickWong I implicitly assumed $q\neq p$ because we are looking at $\frac{(p-1)^p+1}{p^2}$, which is easily shown to be coprime to $p$.

Comment: This could be on par with the famous question whether the Mersenne numbers with prime exponent and the Fermat numbers are all squarefree , with the difference that in this case we have a huge restriction , namely that a prime disproving this must be a Wieferich prime. But here , it appears to be similar difficult to find a counterexample , if it exists.

Comment: Intriguingly, $(p - 1)^p + 1 = np^2$. So, is $\frac{(p - 1)^p + 1}{p^2}$ "like" $(p - 1)^p + 1$, in any way? Closer $p^2$ is to $1$, the better the chances that $\frac{(p - 1)^p + 1}{p^2}$ *isn't* square free. Ergo, the conjecture, if it is that $\frac{(p - 1)^p + 1}{p^2}$ *is* square-free, is likely true.

Comment: Too, $(p - 1)^p + 1 = \left(2n\right)^p + 1$. So, is $\frac{\left(2n\right)^p + 1}{p^2}$ square-free?

Comment: It has to be that $\left(2n\right)^p + 1 = p^2q^2k$

Comment: According to my calculations , $q$ must exceed $10^{10}$ , so finding a counterexample will be very difficult.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but two tidbits: As $(p-1)^p + 1 = m p^3 + p^2$ for some integer $m$, we can write $N = \frac{(p-1)^p + 1}{p^2} = mp + 1 = ks^2$, where $k$ is square free. In this format the goal is to prove there are only solutions with $s=1$, making $N$ square free. The other tidbit (from numerical tests), it appears $N \equiv 1 \text{ or } 7 \pmod{24}$. That restricts $s \equiv 1 \pmod{24}$, and $k \equiv 1 \text{ or } 5 \pmod{24}$.

Comment: It seems that if $q$ is some prime factor of $(p-1)^p + 1$ other than $p$ then $q\equiv 1 \left(\mod p\right)$

Comment: @JuanMoreno Yes, this is true because by using primitive roots of $p^2$.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that $(p-1)^{2k+1} +1$, where $k>0$ and $2k+1<p$, is always square free, so it seems that the property you have identified could be a particular case of a more general one

Comment: What is implied from knowing the answer to this question?