# What are the next primes/semiprimes of the form $\frac{(n-1)^n+1}{n^2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization

This question is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840134/82961)

For an odd positive integer $n$ , define $$f(n):=\frac{(n-1)^n+1}{n^2}$$ as in the linkes question.

> For which $n$ is this expression prime , for which $n$ semiprime ?

We get a prime for $n=5$ and $n=19$ and no other $n\le 10^4$. Also , there is no perfect power for $n\le 10^4$. The first few semiprime cases can be found with PARI/GP using the self-defined function

f(n)=((n-1)^n+1)/n^2

and the code

```
gp > forstep(j=1,50,2,s=f(j);if(bigomega(s)==2,print(j,"   ",component(factor(s),1)~)))
7   [29, 197]
9   [19, 87211]
17   [354689, 2879347902817]
47   [659, 969475768419121812072683722330195828343461703895587337828075618847710907]
gp >
```

The next semiprime has a spectacular factorization :

FF  53  88  (52^53+1)/2809<88> = 181194015068926422899222020415627<33> · 1743739577...51<56>

And the next has an incredible factorization (I wonder whether it was found by ECM or the quadratic sieve) :

FF  103     203     (102^103+1)/10609<203> = 1657792308...87<74> · 4371325251...23<130>

What are the next $n$'s in both cases ?

Comment: No easy way to parallel the forstep ?

Comment: And component can be taken to factor(s)[,1]~

Comment: The factorization of  (102^103+1)/10609 was done in 10/2013 with SNFS see: https://mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=355754&postcount=354.